# How to add to List Generic on each button clicks

Tags: c#, list, xaml, object, generics

I have a button that gets items from controls and add to a list.
As shown

This is my ojects thats holds the values.

```
public class SelectedPurchaseItems
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public double PurchasePrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
}
```

This is my mainwindow class that does the adding to the list

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{ 
    public List<SelectedPurchaseItems> SelectedList;

    private void btnSaveModalSelectItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {  
            SelectedList = new List<SelectedPurchaseItems>();
            SelectedPurchaseItems _value = new SelectedPurchaseItems()
            {
                ItemId = Convert.ToInt32(comboboxSelectItemItem.SelectedValue),
                ItemName = comboboxSelectItemItem.Text,
                PurchasePrice = _purchasePrice,
                Quantity = _quantity,
                UnitOfMeasure = comboboxSelectItemUnitofMeasure.Text,
                Total = _total
            };
            SelectedList.Add(_value);
            DataGridSelectedPurchaseItems.ItemsSource = SelectedList;
    }
}
```

My challenge now is, any time it adds an item to the List, it always reinitialize the list, which makes the previous item added to clear off.
But my aim is for the List to hold each item that has been added to it, and i don't know how to go about that.

I'm also Binding the list to a WPF datagrid. So after showing the first added item, it won't display any further added item.

Comment: You have to remove this line `SelectedList = new List<SelectedPurchaseItems>();` from the method, it always reinitialize the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SelectedList = new List<SelectedPurchaseItems>();
```

is the line that reinitializes your list. You should just delete it, and move initial list initialization to a constructor or somwhere else

Answer (score 0):

Dont re-instantiate it in the button click. Simply initialise it once as shown:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{ 
    public List<SelectedPurchaseItems> SelectedList = new List<SelectedPurchaseItems>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataGridSelectedPurchaseItems.ItemsSource = SelectedList;
    }

    private void btnSaveModalSelectItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {  
        SelectedPurchaseItems _value = new SelectedPurchaseItems()
        {
            ItemId = Convert.ToInt32(comboboxSelectItemItem.SelectedValue),
            ItemName = comboboxSelectItemItem.Text,
            PurchasePrice = _purchasePrice,
            Quantity = _quantity,
            UnitOfMeasure = comboboxSelectItemUnitofMeasure.Text,
            Total = _total
        };
        SelectedList.Add(_value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done this `public List<SelectedPurchaseItems> SelectedList = new List<SelectedPurchaseItems>();

private void btnSaveModalSelectItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
         ...`  and still doesn't work.

Comment: @MIchealDavid - Did you also delete the `SelectedList = new List<SelectedPurchaseItems>();` line in the click method?

Comment: Yeah, and i'm trying to bind it to a DataGrid on each click `DataGridSelectedPurchaseItems.ItemsSource = SelectedList;`. But after displaying the first added, it won't display any added item again.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show where you have `DataGridSelectedPurchaseItems.ItemsSource = SelectedList;`, also add Tags to indicate this is WPF.